# Rails View not rendered through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a show.html file which has`<a ng-click="writeReview(product)" class="vote-link">Review</a>`.

My javascript file contains

```
$scope.writeReview =(product) ->  
  $http.get("/products/#{product.id}/review/new")
```

which calls new method in my ReviewsController.

The corresponding route is  `get '/products/:product_id/review/new', to: "reviews#new", defaults: { format: 'html' }`

**But the problem is that the view is not rendered in views/reviews/new.html.erb on click of Review button in show.html.**

But when i hit the route `products/2/review/new` from URL bar the view is rendered. Even the logs for both the calls i.e, from the Review button from html file as well hit from direct URL bar are same.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding this lines to your js:

```
$scope.writeReview =(product) -> 
 $location.path '/products/' + product.id + '/review/new'
 $location.replace()
```

Comment: Thanks..But  window.location.href = "/products/#{product.id}/review/new" did the trick for me !